# Почему поставлена запятая?

Tags: грамотная-речь, пунктуация

А как объяснить запятую в предложении:

`В преддверии Дня Победы комсомольчане почтили память своего земляка, героя Советского Союза Алексея Маресьева.` (запятая при уточнении или приложении)

А где здесь приложение и определяемое слово? По всей видимости, здесь два приложения (земляк, герой), но они неоднородные и стоят перед именем собственным, тогда как объяснить запятую? Спасибо, если поможете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В преддверии Дня Победы комсомольчане почтили память своего земляка - Героя Советского Союза Алексея Маресьева. Здесь приложение "Героя Советского Союза Алексея Маресьева" стоит в конце предложения и носит пояснительный характер, поэтому нужно тире

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Comment: А если предложение: На фотографии изображен наш земляк Герой Советского Союза Шолыгин. Здесь запятая или тире нужны после "земляк"? Или все зависит от интонации автора?

Comment: На мой взгляд, здесь не обязательно ставить запятые

Comment: В таком случае меня учили рассуждать так: земляк - обязательно Герой Советского Союза? А Герой - обязательно земляк? Нет! Поэтому запятая не нужна